# Remove text from a dynamic file based on data in a static file

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that generates data that is sent to the file Dynamic.txt. The script generates a list of servers that meet very specific criteria.  The list is then processed.  However I have about 20 servers that meet the criteria that I do not want in the list.

This is my static list.  I can remove the servers from the list using the `Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "xxx", ""}` command.  However this is messy and I want cleaner code.  How can I remove data from Dynamic.txt based on data in Static.txt?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Compare-Object cmdlet.

> The Compare-Object cmdlet compares two sets of objects. One set of
>   objects is the Reference set, and the other set is the Difference set.

Here's some example code.

Contents of colors.txt:

```
red
green
blue
pink
```

Contents of notcolors.txt:

```
green
```

Command and output:

```
compare-object (Get-Content "notcolors.txt") (Get-Content "colors.txt") | FL


InputObject   : red
SideIndicator : =>

InputObject   : blue
SideIndicator : =>

InputObject   : pink
SideIndicator : =>
```

Simply selecting InputObject from the results should give you the correct list of servers.

This is powershell, there are other ways too.  You could use a filter somewhere in the script that might go something like this ( you might have to switch around the $_.Name and Get-Content portions to get the logic right.)

```
...| Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch (Get-Content serverlist.txt)} | ...
```

Comment: It probably wouldn't be a good idea to place `Get-Content` in the `Where-Object` statement since the entire file will be read for every object that passes through the pipeline. The operator should be `-notcontains`, and the array of static servers should be on the left side of the operator (although, in PowerShell v3 there is the `-NotIn` operator which requires that the array be on the right side). `Where-Object` should have `{}` around the conditional statement.

Comment: @RaleighBP - Note that if there happen to be any servers in the static list that are not in the dynamic list, the `Compare-Object` CmdLet will return servers from the static list as well, and you'll have to check the `SideIndicator`

Answer (score 1):

To remove entries from one text file based on entries in another text file,

```
$dynamic = Get-Content .\Dynamic.txt
$static = Get-Content .\Static.txt

$dynamic| where { $static -notcontains $_ }| Set-Content .\Dynamic.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Say content of diff.txt should be equal to difference of fileX and fileY then use the below code

```
$fileA = 'fileA.txt'
$fileB = 'fileB.txt'
$diff = 'diff.txt'

$fileAContent = Get-Content $fileA -Encoding UTF8
$fileBContent = Get-Content $fileB -Encoding UTF8
$fileAContent| where { $fileBContent -notcontains $_ }| Set-Content $diff
```